# Does the technique compare-and-swap PREVENT accessing the same memory location concurrently?

Tags: multithreading, concurrency, thread-safety, race-condition, thread-synchronization

Does a CAS operation guarantee that no other thread will access the same memory location in question (during the process) AT THE SAME TIME **or what does the bold text refer to**?

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap

> In computer science, compare-and-swap (CAS) is an atomic instruction
> used in multithreading to achieve synchronization. It compares the
> contents of a memory location with a given value and, only if they are
> the same, modifies the contents of that memory location to a new given
> value. This is done as a single atomic operation. **The atomicity
> guarantees that the new value is calculated based on up-to-date
> information; if the value had been updated by another thread in the
> meantime, the write would fail**. The result of the operation must
> indicate whether it performed the substitution; this can be done
> either with a simple boolean response (this variant is often called
> compare-and-set), or by returning the value read from the memory
> location (not the value written to it).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can think about it that way.  If the CAS succeeds, you are guaranteed that no other thread wrote to the memory location in between the "compare" and the "swap".

Some architectures simply lock that memory location (or cache line) during the operation so that other writes are impossible.  On such architectures the CAS will always succeed.  On other architectures (so-called [LL/SC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Load-link/store-conditional)), the core doing the CAS may simply monitor the memory location, and if another write occurs at the wrong time, the CAS will not do its write and indicate failure instead.

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that anybody who thinks they can benefit by using CAS had better be aware of [the ABA problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABA_problem).

Comment: hi @Nate Eldredge good answer +1 , anyway, we CAN ALSO (not to risk) add a lock (mutex for example) to avoid a data race as I understand that only some computers (multi-core cpu) support this technique "by default", right?

Comment: thanks @Solomon Slow, well, I'll take a look, thanks + 1

Comment: @Daniel: Of course you can add a lock, but if so then you didn't need the atomic CAS in the first place.  (Actually, your mutex is probably implemented within the library or OS using a CAS or similar atomic operation.)  You'll know whether your language supports CAS by its documentation; typically, on single-core systems where atomicity is not a concern, your language's CAS function may be implemented in a simpler and cheaper way without needing such special instructions.  (Though even single-core systems still need atomicity with respect to interrupts.)

Comment: excellent answer @Nate Eldredge, "Though even single-core systems still need atomicity with respect to interrupts." This is because a CAS SHOULD BE an uninterruptible operation and single core CPUs perform virtualized parallelization (context switches), right? + 1

Comment: @Daniel: Yes, exactly.

Comment: excellent @Nate Eldredge now I understand the single core cpu/context switch relationship.